# Unable to download files using Download manager into app datadir

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I want do download file and store in application data directory

```
    context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0).applicationInfo.dataDir
   //  /data/data/<PackageName>/files
```

but after download complete this folder show empty

Download Manager call

```
dm = (DownloadManager) mContext.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request ("video url");
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("file path /data/data/<PackageName>/files","filename.mp4");
            enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: `folder show empty` how do you check? Also `"file path /data/data/<PackageName>"` is not a valid path

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko using Device file explorer and code too

Comment: is `"file path /data/data/<PackageName>"` your actual path (except package name)?

Comment: /data/data/<PackageName>/files dir

Comment: are you sure that it is? Beacause in the question you at least did not point to the `/files` subdir. Is it hardcoded, or you do that with some code? Can you show the actual line of code (removing package name if need only)?

Comment: yes actually created utils folder which return this path and this path is correct i'm copying some files from assets to same path for some other scenario                                           request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(ThemeVideoUtils.getDownloadFolder(mContext), feed.getId() + ".mp4");

Comment: android 9.0(pie) issue download manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download Manager is not running as part of your app - it's 3rd party application (separate process from technical viewpoint), therefore your data directory is NOT accessible to Download Manager same way as it is not accessible to any other 3rd party application. If you must download it directly there, you need to deal with downloading yourself. Alternatively you can download to location DM can write into and then move the file to your destination folder once it finished.